# getting spring autowiring error on server start

Tags: java, spring

i am working on test example by creating spring3 restful project.i configured and created all the necessary files but while i start my server i get the below error-----

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrac



    --------------------applicationContext.xml file--------------------------
  below is my applicationContext.xml file

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes-->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
    For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.rest.abc" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.nea.spring.services.interfaces.test" />


     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />  

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    </beans>

    -------------------------<abc>-servlet.xml file(spring bean) file-------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Specify a view resolver for JSP files-->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    </beans>


    -----------------------java file ---------------------------
```

below is the file where i made my method which i have to expose via restful

```
    package org.nea.rest.unsr;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
```

Comment: The error message is clear: *No matching bean of type [org.nea.spring.services.interfaces.uniservs.UniservSearchInterface] found for dependency*. Where is the Spring bean implementing this `UniservSearchInterface` interface?

Comment: Hi Nizet. i have edited with my interface and implementation class,please check the same.

Comment: The implementing class must be a Spring bean. Either by declaring it in the XML file, or by annotating it with a Spring annotation (Component or Service for example).

Comment: Nizet in order to add @service on the top of implementation class do i need to put any jar in that project

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @jbnizet comment ...
"The implementing class must be a Spring bean. Either by declaring it in the XML file, or by annotating it with a Spring annotation (Component or Service for example)."

You can add this to appContext :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourbasepackage"/>
```

that will allow you to add the annoation

```
@Service("uniservService")
public class UniservServiceJPAImpl implements UniservSearchInterface {
}
```

and then you'll probably also want these to for more comprehensive annotation processing:

```
<!--Indicates that transaction configuration is defined by Java 5
    annotations on bean classes -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="yourtransactionManager"/>

 <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's @Required and
    @Autowired, as well as JSR 250's @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy and @Resource (if available) -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: HI Nim i included the annotation and the error is something else now .i could guess where is the problem .As i have made different project for my SpringServices, SpringServicesImpl and for multiple project in my workspace i copy these 2 jars in my required project as spring.jar and springservice.jar.now when i do an ant build of one of my project then i create the jar,now can you tell me how do i copy the same jar in my springRest project,or what line i have to add in my build.xml file so that i can copy these 2 jar in my different project of lib folder